# Paypal Payment option not visible in checkout in magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: paypal, paypal-payments-pro

I am using magento 1.9.2.4. and i have configured paypal well. But paypal payment option not visible in checkout page. But i am able to see checkout button in view cart page. Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you try to enable another payment option to check if its visible or not?

Comment: Other payment gateway is visible like razor pay.